# Not able to simulate multiple joints

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to simulate a robotic arm in gazebo and my code works for the first 2 joints but somehow does not work when I add a third. I've tried copying the code for my first joint and just modifying values but it still does not work. Any idea why this is happening? This is the error that i get:

Error:   unnamed joint found
at line 345 in /build/urdfdom-YMMa9X/urdfdom-1.0.0/urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
Error:   joint xml is not initialized correctly
at line 206 in /build/urdfdom-YMMa9X/urdfdom-1.0.0/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp

Here is my code (works if  arm_link_2 and arm_joint_2 are removed):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<robot name='arm' xmlns:xacro='http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro'>

  <xacro:property name="base_l" value="1"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_b" value="1"/>
  <xacro:property name="base_h" value="0.1"/>

  <xacro:property name="blink_l" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="blink_b" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="blink_h" value="0.5"/>

  <xacro:property name="link_l" value="0.5"/>
  <xacro:property name="link_b" value="0.1"/>
  <xacro:property name="link_h" value="0.1"/>

  <xacro:property name="joint_thickness" value="0.1"/>


  <!--arm_link_1-->
  <link name="arm_link_1">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia
        ixx = '0.011'
        ixy = '0'
        ixz = '0'
        iyy = '0.0225'
        iyz = '0'
        izz = '0.0135'
        />
    </inertial>

    <visual name='arm_link_1_visual'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${link_l/2-joint_thickness*0.5} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${link_l} ${link_b} ${link_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='arm_link_1_collision'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${link_l+link_l/2} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${link_l-joint_thickness} ${link_b-joint_thickness} ${link_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="arm_joint_1" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_h+blink_h-1.5*link_h}"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <parent link="blink"/>
    <child link="arm_link_1"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
    <limit effort="10" velocity="1.0" lower="0" upper="100" />
  </joint>



  <!--arm_link_2-->
  <link name="arm_link_2">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia
        ixx = '0.011'
        ixy = '0'
        ixz = '0'
        iyy = '0.0225'
        iyz = '0'
        izz = '0.0135'
        />
    </inertial>

    <visual name='arm_link_2_visual'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${link_l/2-joint_thickness*0.5} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${link_l} ${link_b} ${link_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='arm_link_2_collision'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${link_l+link_l/2} 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${link_l-joint_thickness} ${link_b-joint_thickness} ${link_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint name="arm_joint_2" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="${link_l} 0 ${base_h+blink_h-1.5*link_h}"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <parent link="arm_link_1"/>
    <child link="arm_link_2"/>
    <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
    <limit effort="10" velocity="1.0" lower="0" upper="100" />
  </joint>




  <!--arm_base-->
  <link name='arm_base'>
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1001"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia
        ixx = '166.11'
        ixy = '0'
        ixz = '0'
        iyy = '166.11'
        iyz = '0'
        izz = '166.01'
        />
    </inertial>

    <visual name='base_visual'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${base_h/2}"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_l} ${base_b} ${base_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='base_collision'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${base_h/2}"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${base_l} ${base_b} ${base_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>




  <!--base link-->
  <link name="blink">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia
        ixx = '0.0135'
        ixy = '0'
        ixz = '0'
        iyy = '0.0225'
        iyz = '0'
        izz = '0.0111'
        />
    </inertial>

    <visual name='blink_visual'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${blink_h/2}"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${blink_l} ${blink_b} ${blink_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name='blink_collision'>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 ${blink_h/2}"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="${blink_l} ${blink_b} ${blink_h}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint>
    <joint name="z_axis_rev" type="revolute"/>
    <parent link="arm_base"/>
    <child link="blink"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${base_h}"/>
    <limit effort="10" velocity="1.0" lower="0" upper="100" />
  </joint>


</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394525/not-able-to-simulate-multiple-joints/) by [SHURIMA](https://answers.ros.org/users/94001/shurima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
>   <joint>
> ```

```
    <joint name="z_axis_rev" type="revolute"/>
    [..]
  </joint>
```

you have a `joint` inside a `joint`.

The outer `joint` also doesn't have any of the required attributes.

There is no `name`, nor `type`. Hence the error message:

> ```
> Error: unnamed joint found at line 345 in /build/urdfdom-YMMa9X/urdfdom-1.0.0/urdf_parser/src/joint.cpp
> ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SHURIMA](https://answers.ros.org/users/94001/shurima/) on 2022-01-19**:
ok thank you!